# Como Popular um TreeView com os Diretórios e Arquivos do Sistema em C#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Em minha aplicação (Windows Forms) tenho que fazer uma arvore de diretórios para o usuário buscar por um(ou mais) arquivo(s) dentro do sistema dele.

Vi na Web como fazer essa arvore em um tutorial da Microsoft, mas no exemplo deles a TreeView apenas exibe os diretórios, não os arquivos propriamente ditos (os arquivos são exibidos em uma ListView que não é prático).

A Arvore funciona, mas eu preciso ver os arquivos do Diretório e se possível já seleciona-los (recuperar os FileName deles) para minha aplicação.

Segue o Código.

```
private void PopulateTreeView()
 {
     TreeNode rootNode;

     DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(@"../..");
     if (info.Exists)
     {
         rootNode = new TreeNode(info.Name);
         rootNode.Tag = info;
         GetDirectories(info.GetDirectories(), rootNode);
         treeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
     }
 }

 private void GetDirectories(DirectoryInfo[] subDirs,TreeNode nodeToAddTo)
 {
     TreeNode aNode;
     DirectoryInfo[] subSubDirs;
     foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in subDirs)
     {
         aNode = new TreeNode(subDir.Name, 0, 0);
         aNode.Tag = subDir;
         aNode.ImageKey = "folder";
         subSubDirs = subDir.GetDirectories();
         if (subSubDirs.Length != 0)
         {
             GetDirectories(subSubDirs, aNode);
         }
         nodeToAddTo.Nodes.Add(aNode);
     }
 }
```

Vi nesse tutorial que eu posso aplicar um foreach para cada arquivo encontrado no node e exibi-lo no ListView, mas como adiciona-lo a TreeView ?

Obrigado.

Comment: Você pode dar uma olhada em neste vídeo : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55PCdfvlyYk , ele mostra como você pode exibir os itens no controle do Tree View no diretório especificado .  Assim que estiver com tempo vou tentar postar a postar a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, não posso assistir vídeo no trabalho, mas vou dar uma olhada nesse link quando chegar em casa, muito obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que este exemplo vai te ajudar.

**Diretório dos arquivos**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código**

```
 DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\mmurta\Desktop\PastaMeuSistema\Arquivos_Meu_Sistema");

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Users\mmurta\Desktop\PastaMeuSistema"))
            {
                try
                {
                    DirectoryInfo[] directories = directoryInfo.GetDirectories();

                    foreach (FileInfo file in directoryInfo.get())
                    {
                        if (file.Exists)
                        {
                            TreeNode nodes = treeView.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(file.Name);
                        }
                    }

                    if (directories.Length > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in directories)
                        {
                            TreeNode node = treeView.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(directory.Name);
                            foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
                            {
                                if (file.Exists)
                                {
                                    TreeNode nodes = treeView.Nodes[0].Nodes[node.Index].Nodes.Add(file.Name);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

**Resultado :**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois se preferir você pode realizar o download do o `código fonte` [aqui](http://www.mediafire.com/download/70i9zhuodo0ow2e/TestForm.rar) , foi disponibilizado pelo autor do [Vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55PCdfvlyYk&list=PL-kW5SAS93WFqw6sdPv9k8LnMCsv8U7k-) .

Comment: Opa amigo, no mesmo momento que eu ia postar a resposta você mandou a sua HAHA, obrigado pela ajuda cara.

Comment: Ok , Tente buscar os termos em inglês no google sobre o que você deseja implementar , se mesmo assim a dúvida  bater nos estamos aqui =D. Se você achou adequado meu exemplo por favor marque como resposta*-*.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema, fiz uma lógica para que dentro de cada nó onde tenha arquivos seja criado mais um nó para exibi-los.

segue codigo:

```
    private void PopularTreeView()
    {
        TreeNode rootNode;

        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\codigos");
        if (info.Exists)
        {
            rootNode = new TreeNode(info.Name);
            rootNode.Tag = info;
            GetDirectories(info.GetDirectories(), rootNode);
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
        }
    }

    private void GetDirectories(DirectoryInfo[] subDirs, TreeNode nodeToAddTo)
    {
        TreeNode aNode;
        DirectoryInfo[] subSubDirs;
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in subDirs)
        {
            aNode = new TreeNode(subDir.Name, 0, 0);
            aNode.Tag = subDir;
            aNode.ImageKey = "icone-pasta";
            subSubDirs = subDir.GetDirectories();
            if (subSubDirs.Length != 0)
            {
                GetDirectories(subSubDirs, aNode);
            }
            nodeToAddTo.Nodes.Add(aNode);
            foreach (FileInfo file in subDir.GetFiles())
            {
                TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
                node.Text = file.Name;
                node.ImageIndex = 1;
                node.SelectedImageIndex = 1;
                nodeToAddTo.Nodes.Add(node);
            }
        }
    }
```